# Having trouble with creating a two column data frame (State, Regions) from a one column data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsXa4.png)

I want to split the state names using "[ed" and the regions using "(". I want to have a dataframe with two columns (State and Regions). This is what I am getting so far with my code.

```
ut=pd.read_table(r'university_towns.txt', header=None)
ut.head(50)
a=[]
f=lambda x:x.split('[edit]')[0]
g=lambda x:x.split(' (')[0]
for j,i in ut.iterrows():
   if "[" in i:
      State=i.apply(f,0)
   else:
      RegionName=i.apply(g,0)
   a.append([State, RegionName])
x=pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["State", 'RegionName'])
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rzSH.png)